# What is the difference between an internal/external and public/private function in solidity?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

Currently reading solidity documentation: 
https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#function-types

> By default, function types are internal, so the internal keyword can
>   be omitted. In contrast, contract functions themselves are public by
>   default, only when used as the name of a type, the default is
>   internal.

This does not make sense to me. How can a function be internal and public at the same time?

I know `internal` means functions can only be called within the contract and `external` can be called outside of the contract. So to me, internal is private and external is public but the documentation makes it sound like it can be public and internal at the same time?

So what is the difference, if any, between `internal/external` and `public/private` in regards to functions?

Comment: Your question may be more suited to another StackExchange site. For questions related to the blockchain, Bitcoin and other cryptocurrencies, please ask on the [**Bitcoin StackExchange**](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com) instead. For questions *specific* to Ethereum, please ask on the [**Ethereum StackExchange**](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com) instead. :)

Answer (score 10):

Here is the difference between the four keywords:

`private` means it's only callable from other functions inside the contract

`internal` is like private but can also be called by contracts that inherit from the current one

`external` can only be called outside the contract

`public` can be called anywhere, both internally and externally.

Answer (score 3):

In the terminology of Solidity `internal/external` also uses as description 'two kinds of function calls' and not only as access modifiers.

[Take a look at the documentation section about 'Visibility and Getters' inside the contracts](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters).

> Since Solidity knows two kinds of function calls (internal ones that do not create an actual EVM call (also called a “message call”) and external ones that do), there are four types of visibilities for functions and state variables.